# Generic Interface causes javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException

Tags: java, tomcat, jsf-2, mojarra

I'm struggling with some error that occurs in some (environment) constellations.
- If I run my app on Tomcat in Eclipse-Webtools on WinXP it works.
- Running it in Tomcat on WinXP or Linux the error occurs
- Running it under HPUX works.
- If I remove the generic part it also works everywhere.

**The error:**

```
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /some.xhtml @3,67 value="#{someBean.someDto.id}": Property 'id' not writable on type java.lang.Object
```

**The object that is causing trouble:**

```
public class SomeDto implements SelectableItem<Long>, Serializable {

  private Long id;

  @Override
  public Long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  @Override
  public void setId(final Long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
  ...
}
```

**The generic interface:**

```
public interface SelectableItem<T> {
  public T getId();

  public void setId(T id);
  ...
}
```

Any hints what I'm missing here?

Jonny

Comment: try removing the `final` from `public void setId(final Long id) {`

Comment: hi daniel, thanks for your comment. unfortunately this didn't help.

Comment: Are you using the same version of Java an all your environments? In someBean - is someDto declared as SelectableItem<Long> or as SomeDto?

Comment: Hi munyengm, in SomeBean someDto is declared as SomeDto. I cannot precisely tell you, if they're the exact Java versions on each environment (but I'm pretty sure about that). We're using Version 1.6. But on WinXp it runs well starting it from Eclipse Webtools but fails when deployed to Tomcat manually where the Java Version are exactly the same.

Comment: I am facing the exact same problem on Websfear Portal 7.

Comment: Does the error come from an inputText? How is *someDto* initialized in *SomeBean*? Scope of *SomeBean*?